# Get form field position with pdflib and pCos

Tags: forms, pdf, field, pdflib

For one project, I have to get the form fields of the pdf in the right order, I use pdflib but the fields are not extracted in the same position than they appear in the PDF. 
I rode that we can extract the form field position with pCos but I don't find the solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try something? Please provide your current code sample.

Comment: I just try things like that : 
p->pcos_get_string($this->indoc, "fields[" . $idField . "]/position");
But it doesn't exists. 
In the documentation there is nothing mentionned about form fields position.
It's just mentionned in the datasheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can retrieve the rectangle of a form field with pCos by using the "/Rect"  dictionary of the fields. A very simple (java based sample) looks like in this way:

```
        String rect_path = "fields[" + f + "]/Rect";
        if (p.pcos_get_string(doc, "type:" + rect_path).equals("array")
            && (int) p.pcos_get_number(doc, "length:" + rect_path) == 4) {
          System.out.print("[");
          for (int i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) {
            if (i > 0) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print(p.pcos_get_number(doc, rect_path + "[" + i + "]"));
          }
          System.out.print("], "); 
        }
```

The "Rect" dictionary contains four values, with the lower left and upper right coordinates of the form field. So you can loop over of the dictionary and retrieve the values.

you might find further samples in the [pCOS cookbook](http://www.pdflib.com/pcos-cookbook/interactive-elements/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
In which order are the values ? 
And do you know if we can know on which page is the field ?

Comment: you get here two pairs of x/y values. In general first the lower left and as second the upper right corner of the field. No you can't retrieve the page in this way. You might determine this via the pCOS annots array.

Comment: please see PDF specification (ISO 32000/PDF 1.7) section "12.5 Annotations" for details. You find this on http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html

Comment: Sometimes the "Rect" of a field is null, there is no way to have the position of these fields ?